# How to run Protractor in Bamboo CI

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, bamboo

I am trying to run my protractor test case in Bamboo CI but it throws an installation error.

I am able to install node modules using npm task but somehow I am not able to install and run protractor in my bamboo plan. Is there a different way of doing it or I am doing something wrong.

Please find attach the snapshot from my bamboo plan :

Npm install 
[image]

Protractor Task

[image]

And my error log is as follow

```
/tmp/RDMPDEV-MAP-JOB1-91-ScriptBuildTask-6009702493071779000.sh: line 1: protractor: command not found
```

Please advice

Comment: did you ever get this to work? I too am trying to get protractor to work on bamboo. I cannot get ng serve to run in the background so that I can execute protractor.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention commands for protractor and web-driver installation. Do following:

1. Write below commands into Command* text filed under npm configurations section. Either put all commands separate by a comma or add one more configuration section if you could see any such option. or check in advanced options

Commands:

```
 install -g protractor

 webdriver-manager update
```

2. Write 'webdriver-manger start' as first line in script body and then write 'protractor conf.js'

You should mention all test spec in conf.js file and run conf.js file from  script body.

Script body looks like:

```
 1. webdriver-manager start
 2. protractor conf.js
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue, following are the steps I followed:
1 - Added npm configuration task - install protractor (without -g as it was causing permission denied issue).
2 - Added npm configuration task - webdriver-manager update (but this task gives error)
and I could not move past this issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can also trigger protractor tests in bamboo via angular cli command `e2e`.
Definition of e2e in `package.json`

```
"e2e": "ng e2e --no-serve --base-href"
```

Please refer below  screenshot showing this configuration in bamboo.
Remember to add commandline parameter to e2e command in bamboo as required like `--base-href`

[image]